# quadratic eqn solver only solve for quadratic equation with variable x

Tags: python

```
x = input(" write a quadratic equation ")
x=(x.replace(" ",""))
```

I wrote this to remove all the spaces from the input so that indexing becomes easy

```
q = x.find("x")
w=int(q+1)
```

The code worked well but the indexes in the code depended upon the index of x
It cant work if someone wrote a equation with a differnt variable then x
Below is the whole code

```
x = input(" write a quadratic equation ")
print ("")
x=(x.replace(" ",""))

q = x.find("x")

w=int(q+1)

abc = x[0:q+1]
bcd = x[w+1:]

if (x[w]!="^") :
    y=abc + "^2" +bcd
    y=(y.replace(" ",""))
    print(y)
else: 
    print(x,end ="""
    
""")

A = int(x[:w-1])


e=x.rfind("x")


B=int(x[w+1:e])


C=int(x[e+1:])


r=(((-B) - ((B*B)-(4*A*C))**(1/2))/            ((2*A)))
t=(((-B) + ((B*B)-(4*A*C))**(1/2))/((2*A)))
print( "the roots are " ,r,"and" ,t)
```

How can i make the code work for all letters
Is there any way i can change the letters in the input to 1letters i.e.x

Comment: it does not accept "x^2"

Comment: You can prompt the user to input what is the variable: `var = input("Your variable: ")` and simply replace every occurence of `'x'` with `var`

Comment: @JohnColeman Yeah, that *might* be a better solution. But using the `ast` module is absolutely irrational for a python beginner.

Comment: @Scotty1- True, but it doesn't hurt for a beginner to know about the existence of the module and to know that they are engaged in something called "parsing". Plant seeds for the future. I heard about `ast` long before I actually used it.

Comment: @john , i tried understanding `ast` but i wasnt able to clearly understand that .is there any other solution to my prob??

Comment: One possibility is to replace `'-'` by `'+-'` and then split on `'+'`. This will give you a list of terms, which would be easier to parse than the overall equation. For example, `'3x^2 -4x+5'` could be turned into the list `['3x^2','-4x','5']`

Comment: ```import string
x = ("1a^2 - 6a + 6")
x=x.replace(string.ascii_lowercase ,"x")
print(x)``` i tried this but its not working

Comment: Your `x` has no occurrences of the exact string `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`, so when you ask Python to change such substrings to `'x'`, nothing happens. You would need to *iterate* over `string.ascii_lowercase` character by character.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking through each character in `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`, and calling `x.find(character)`. If this returns `-1`, then the character is not present. Repeat iteration until a character is found and assume that this character is the variable to solve for.

```
equation = input("Write a quadratic equation: ")
print("")
equation = equation.replace(" ","")

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
index = -1
i = 0

while index == -1:
    index = equation.find(alphabet[i])
    i += 1

letter = equation[index]

# continue rest of program from here, assuming letter variable is the character to solve for
```